# How do I safely change properties on my skybox?

Tags: unity, materials, skybox

Usually in Unity, when your scripts make changes to something at runtime, those changes are not persisted back to design-time.  This is generally considered a good thing.  But for whatever bizarre technical reason, this does not apply to shader properties on materials.  If you change something while the game is running, it stays changed!

Generally the way to get around this is with a `MaterialPropertyBlock`, which also helps avoid generating a lot of garbage.  But `MaterialPropertyBlock`s work with `Renderer`s, which leaves out one rather important material: the skybox.

Right now, I have code that says `RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_PropName", value);`, and it's incredibly aggravating because it always needs to be reset afterwards.  `RenderSettings` doesn't have a `SkyboxRenderer` property that I can use in conjunction with a `MaterialPropertyBlock`, so how can I change shader settings on my skybox and make them not persist after I exit play mode?

Comment: The "bizarre technical reason" being the same reason that applies to every asset in your project folder but not in your scene: if you don't instantiate a copy (like the copy of a game object spawned when loading a scene), then you're modifying the original.

Comment: @DMGregory I don't instantiate copies of the game objects when I'm loading the scenes.  Unity's perfectly capable of taking care of that for me in order to protect the originals.  But for some bizarre technical reason, it doesn't do the same for the skybox.

Comment: Loading a scene *is* instantiating a copy. Once you enter play mode you're no longer manipulating the saved scene file on your hard disc, you've spawned newly-created instances of all its contents.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you considered doing something like...

```
Material originalSkybox = RenderSettings.skybox;
Material runtimeSkybox = Instantiate(originalSkybox);
RenderSettings.skybox = runtimeSkybox;

runtimeSkybox.SetFloat(...
```

...and destroying `runtimeSkybox` when your game ends?

Comment: No, actually the thought never crossed my mind to `Instantiate` something that's not a `GameObject`.  Does that even work?  Only time I've ever seen `Instantiate` used is with prefabs.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Instantiate really mostly just makes a copy of something. It works with... nearly anything.